# Could an electric engine provide the same performance as jet engines on current aircraft?

Tags: airliner, electric-engine

I have looked at various questions on this SE site regarding this topic but I have not really found a satisfactory answer. Some comments [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-ducted-fans-in-designs-such-as-the/9949#comment19200_9949) regarding torque and power in electric motors vs gasoline engines were helpful. Additional info also found [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19569/how-many-kilowatts-to-get-an-electric-747-8-airborne).

Underlying my question is the assumption that battery technology will considerably advance from what is available commercially now. Simply assume that providing the electric motor with enough power is not an issue and that the weight of the battery is equal to fuel.

**Is it possible to build an electric aircraft engine that would allow current commercial airplanes the same capabilities as jet engines available today do?**

Comment: Assuming the question is about the engines only (and we are gifted infinite battery performance) - the only thing I can think of is electric engines can't do afterburner/reheat. However I believe very few **commercial** aircraft have ever offered this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I am asking only about engine (and plane) capabilities. I was wondering if there are any inherent characteristics that make electric motors unsuited for use as aircraft engines?

Comment: One problem is in the name: turbofans / turboprops rely on the *turbo* mechanic, i.e. fuel is burnt, exhaust used to drive a shaft, which in turn is ramming more air into the combustion chamber, allowing for higher pressures to build, increasing the power available. The whole concept won't work for electric engines, because there is no exhaust to work with and pressure is not (that) relevant for the efficiency of the engine. You'll probably be looking at "normal" propellers and limited speed for the time being, unless I've overlooked a way to drive a non-turbo above usual propeller speeds.

Comment: If you're using an electric motor, it wouldn't be a turbofan but rather a ducted fan. Modern jets have a turbine engine core with large bypass fans surrounding. The electric motor would replace the entire core of the turbine so you're left with a ducted fan.

Comment: @DevSolar I would suppose that a ducted fan wouldn't have the same speed limitation that turboprops experience. I'm thinking of something similar to high-bypass turbofans but with an electric core. I'm no expert but it seems similar to me.

Comment: Ill your battery weight be burnt in fly? Even if you pair each property of the engine/fuel system my actual airliner get lighter a few tons/hour

Comment: I submit that you can't simply handwave battery tech away. Li-ion batteries provide about 250 Wh/l and 350 Wh/Kg. Most petroleum distillates (from gasoline to jet fuel) are around 9000 Wh/l and 13,500 Wh/Kg. And there are good reasons (like its atomic weight and high half-reaction potential) why we're unlikely to do better than lithium.

Comment: The fundamental problem here is the laws of thermodynamics. Assuming you had a battery that could power the equivalent of a jet, it would cost more in fuel to charge the battery then to use jet fuel directly. This is the problem with electric cars today.

Comment: No, @user3344003, that's not the problem with electric cars. You're forgetting that an electric car is about five times more efficient at turning stored watt-hours into movement as an ICE car. So even if your charge/discharge round-trip efficiency is only 50% (and it's actually much better, around 80% or more) the electric car will still use fewer watt-hours. But in an airplane the battery mass is a much worse problem, because you have constantly spend energy to keep it airborne. Keeping the electric car (and its battery) rolling on the ground is not nearly as much of a load.

Comment: You still have to generate the electricity and transmit the electricity to the car. Compare the cost of heating a house with gas v. electricity.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/impossible-electric-airplane-takes-flight/

Comment: "assume that providing the electric motor with enough power is not an issue" stop focusing on batteries and there associated weight. assume the electricity is coming from some soon to be invented super efficient lightweight nuclear reactor.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Not yet.

To look at a medium-range aircraft, let's base the engine on the [CFM56](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFM_International_CFM56) or the [IAE V2500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAE_V2500). Those engines produce between 100 and 150 kN static thrust. In cruise, their thrust is [considerably lower](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~propulsi/propulsion/jets/tfans/cfm56.html) due to the low density in cruise altitude and due to them moving at Mach 0.8. Let's use a value of 25 kN - this is enough so that two of them will comfortably push an [A320](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A320_family) class airframe through the thin air at altitude.

The power to produce such an amount of thrust is force times speed. The speed when flying with Mach 0.8 in [35.000 ft](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=speed%20of%20sound%20at%2035000%20ft%20altitude) is 240 m/s, so the power produced by one engine is 6.0 MW. Now [let's look up how big and heavy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-to-weight_ratio#Electric_motors.2FElectromotive_generators) an electric motor has to be to produce 6 MW continuously. As you can see from the linked Wikipedia page, the results are all over the place. Big, industrial motors come in at less than 1 kW/kg, so our motor would weigh more than 6 tons. The smaller motors for electric airplanes are pushing 10 kW/kg, the power-to-weight ratio of the [GE90 turbofan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_GE90), but will lose some of that when scaled up to size. Remember, even at 98% efficiency the motor will generate 120 kW of heat - this needs to be removed, and operating in thin air doesn't make this easy.

With current technology the motor could achieve maybe 2 to 3 kW/kg - this means the motor driving our hypothetical engine comes in at 2 to 3 tons. Add to this the fan and the fairing of the jet engine (we will not need the high-pressure part and all the turbines), but double the fan weight because we need to compensate for the missing high-energy core flow. This will maybe weigh 50% of the CFM56 / V2500, so we need to add another 1.2 tons.

The electric motor will be twice as heavy as the parts it replaces. There is still some work to do before it can gain an advantage over current jet engines, but it has some potential because it does not dump half of the energy supplied to it overboard in a hot, fast-moving, noisy gas stream.

---

EDIT:

Since so many people get excited about me omitting the energy density aspect of electric propulsion, even though the question did expressly desire to leave this out, here are **two** things to consider. Energy density is only half of the problem of electric storage.

1. The [energy density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density#Energy_densities_of_common_energy_storage_materials) of jet fuel is around 43 MJ/kg, while Lithium polymer batteries achieve not even one MJ/kg. But this comparison is linear thinking - realistically, the current will be produced either by a high-efficiency turbine-generator combination, or by fuel cells, burning hydrogen at twice the efficiency of a conventional jet engine. Since hydrogen packs 142 MJ per kilogram, at twice the efficiency the electric airliner would need only 162 kg of hydrogen for every ton of kerosene in a conventional jet. Yes, I know, even then its volume will still be a problem.
2. If any form of batteries is used, the fact that empty batteries weigh as much as full ones is the final nail in the coffin of battery-powered flight. While your average long-range jet [lands at 60% of its take-off weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_fraction), the battery-powered jet would need to schlepp those heavy batteries all the way to the final destination. To be competitive, those hypothetical batteries would need to have **twice** the energy density of kerosene.

Comment: The engines you've mentioned are built for durability and to withstand some rather violent mishandling. Nobody asked them to be light :) So indeed there's still a road ahead to improve the weght/power ration :)

Comment: This analysis doesn't consider the weight of the power supply for the electric plane versus the weight of fuel for the jet.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: Please read the question. And understand it.

Comment: @GabrielVince: The Prius engine is 1.37 kW/kg. It is built for low weight - it is a car engine, not a stationary industry motor. I assumed 2 - 3 kW/kg, well knowing that weight is a premium in aircraft, but with current technology you will not get any better than that. After all, this motor needs to be certified just like any other component on the aircraft. Things would be different for Formula 1, but we are still looking at civil aviation here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - exactly what I was looking for. One aspect I did not anticipate was the problem of dissipating the heat produced by the electric motor, very interesting.

Comment: @RussellBorogove from the question `Simply assume that providing the electric motor with enough power is not an issue and that the weight of the battery is equal to fuel.` No analysis of the weight of the power supply is necessary for _this particular_ question.

Comment: @FreeMan Actually, the weight still is a problem even if you assume it's equal. See my answer. Though, of course, you're right that that analysis of what those weights would be isn't necessary, since it's assumed.

Comment: @lexeter I don't think that will be such a big problem. I ran the numbers, and the heat dissipation (measured in W/m²) would already less than your average CPU heat dissipation if your engine had only 1m² external surface area available. Although it is a problem for automotive applications, where a large supply of cold air will necessitate large, ugly scoops, this is arguably less of a problem for something that will basically be a giant desktop fan.

Comment: @sanchises Try covering a square meter in high-end CPUs running at full load and see how well air cooling works. :)

Comment: @reirab I specifically said 'average' CPU's (45W/269mm²). Secondly, try cooling that square meter with a 900km/h -50°C airflow - quite a difference from a CPU cooler (even a high-end).

Comment: @sanchises Ah, I missed the average part. Still, I'd wager you'll have trouble even with that kind of airflow, especially at the atmospheric pressure where airliners fly (1/3 to 1/4 of sea-level values.)

Comment: @sanchises Thank you for running the numbers! I am not doubting your calculation super powers but did you consider the reduced air density at altitude? Although I assume that while the thin air makes it difficult to dissipate heat it is also very cold which in turn should help. No idea, however, which of the two has a greater impact. Probably not easy to answer since it depends on many factors.

Comment: @lexeter Feel free to doubt my calculation powers ;-) And, I didn't calculate the actual engine temperature, only a order-of-magnitude. If you're really interested, the book 950+ page book I have on it (Foundations of Heat Transfer, F.Incropera et al) is a good start.

Comment: Turbofan engines manage to dissipate a whole lot of heat from the core. Not all of it goes out the exhaust. I don't know if it's equivalent

Comment: The hydrogen fuel cell energy density is puny. A hundred times that is available, but not used for other reasons.

Comment: "Remember, even at 98% efficiency the motor will generate 120 kW of heat - this needs to be removed, and operating in thin air doesn't make this easy." Yet a jet engine manages to remove much more heat in the same atmosphere. Perhaps you could attach some kind of electric fan onto the electric fan for cooling.... funnily enough 98% is at the range of the limit of the Carnot efficiency (assuming the air isn't liquid nitrogen and the engine is operating under the melting temperature of tungsten).

Comment: *"an electric motor has to be to produce 6 MW continuously."* Are you suggesting that jet engines run at 100% throttle during the entire flight?  Electric motors can handle a higher power intermittently (ie, during takeoff) than their rated power if they are designed to do so.  There may not be nice examples available commercially, but like jet engines an airplane electric motor would necessarily be customized to the application, and you should probably be looking for a motor somewhere closer to cruising power than maximum power.

Comment: Didn't know till today that "schlepp" also exists in english language :*)

Comment: Good comments on this subject, Peter.  Yeah the chief problem lies in the weight of the motors as well as the energy densities of current battery technology.  One idea might be the use of chemical fuels powering fuel cells and using the excess heat from the cells and the motor to increase the enthalpy of air from the ducted fan into the nozzle, creating additional reactive thrust.  This is just a concept and I haven't done a back of the envelope calculation to see if the combined weight of the motor, fuel cell, heat exchanger, etc would be lighter than existing jet engines.

Comment: @CarloFelicione: I agree, fuel cells could be an option. Their weight has come down quite a bit in the last 20 years, but they need to shrink by another order of magnitude to be ahead of all other options.

Comment: @AdamDavis Note that my 6MW number is already for cruise. At take-off, fuel flow and thrust are much higher. Yes, and I am suggesting that jet engines do run at 100% throttle, or close to it. They do this to be able to fly as high as possible in order to increase efficiency.

Comment: Hydrogen does not pack 142 MJ per kilogram.  That requires some magical container that will never exist.  Hydrogen requires extremely heavy pressure tanks and/or extremely heavy cryo systems with bulky/heavy insulation, and/or low pressure composite tanks that monopolize aircraft volume and have retention and icing problems. ...  There is a reason that, despite many attempts, hydrogen aircraft remain: rare, overpriced, and under-performing.

Comment: @BrockAdams As far as I know, the hydrogen in Zeppelins needed not much more than a [lightweight bag of goldbeater's skin](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31503/what-materials-are-used-for-the-gas-bags-in-hydrogen-airships/31511#31511). And it still contained [between 120 and 142 MJ per kg](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2005/MichelleFung.shtml) of potential energy. Please explain what is so magical about Zeppelins. They did exist!

Comment: @PeterKämpf, zepplins were not *powered* by hydrogen (they used gasoline or diesel). If they were, their range would only have been a few miles. (Actually much less as they'd almost immediately lose buoyancy and crash.)  On earth, you can't use hydrogen for propulsion at anywhere near 120 MJ/kg because of the equipment needed to store it.

Comment: @BrockAdams: Then [this](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/18809/are-there-any-programs-to-build-a-hydrogen-powered-airplane/18816#18816) might surprise you. Please don't overlook the paragraph about Blaugas. This type of fuel contained hydrogen and was buoyancy-neutral.

Comment: @PeterKämpf, that zeppelin had an awful lot of petrol tanks for a "hydrogen powered" craft. Still Wikipedia says it could go 100 hrs on hydrogen alone (but it cites a source which says no such thing). ... Even if this was true, you'll note that the system performance is just a *skosh* below that of jet powered aircraft, per the question.

Comment: Any fuel based electric generation would defeat the point of an electric motor. You could just as easily feed hydrogen into an ICE or jet engine (or heaven forbid, rocket engine).

Comment: @Aron: Not necessarily. If you compare the efficiency of fuel cells plus electric motors with that of a gas turbine, the fuel cell wins hands down.

Comment: @PeterKämpf Let's assume batteries make up 75% of a plane's weight @ a future value of 500 Wh/kg = 1.8 MJ/kg. Then I calculate for the same energy storage, hydrogen + storage + fuel cells for the same airframe, etc. would take up ~10% of the plane's weight if they're 80% efficient. If induced drag is roughly half the drag on the airplane in the battery case, then the induced drag gets cut to ~10% of the battery case, but let's call it zero. So for fuel cells, you have half the drag of the battery case, and half of the power requirement.

Comment: @PeterKämpf Currently, electrolysis is about ~60% efficient, though. So you will need roughly the same energy that would be put onto the batteries in the plane, anyway. The cost difference per trip is close to zero. And that's not considering having to deal with the extremely pernicious hydrogen molecule, which you're either going to have as a cryogenic and costly to handle/store liquid or a gas with a volume larger than that of the batteries. Since the energy density increase of batteries seems inevitable, it mostly  has to do with the cost reduction on the battery side.

Comment: _With current technology the motor could achieve maybe 2 to 3 kW/kg_

Existing motors on propeller electric aircraft achieve 5kW/Kg, on Siemens Extra 330LE. High-temperature superconducting motors are demonstrated at ~8kW/kg, with good prospects of going about twice as high very soon.

Comment: @kert: Thank you for the information! I answered the question with current knowledge one year ago, and considering that the engine power is "five times more than comparable drive systems" ([source](http://www.siemens.com/press/en/feature/2015/corporate/2015-03-electromotor.php?content[]=Corp)) the answer is almost prescient. The more spectacular power/weight ratios are only possible with smaller engines; once you scale up to airliner scales, 8 or 10 are still impossible.

Comment: Actually, NASA has a design for 41kW/Kg at 12 megawatt scale. High temperature superconductors. 

See https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20150023038.pdf

Comment: @kert: Since you did not really read what you linked to: This is a projection using some heroic assumptions. Please note that I talked of the state of the art. The fine twisted MgB$_2$ simply isn't here yet, wishful thinking of NASA nonwithstanding. The question is about current aircraft, not NASA propaganda thought up to increase funding.

Comment: No i did read this, and other materials too. The same research team in collaboration with AFRL has produced working motors with HTS at 8kW/Kg before, its referenced in plenty of other research. Doubling that achievement is on near term horizon, and >40kW/Kg is modeled, with no fundamental constraints.

Comment: @PeterKämpf Fancy providing a calculation at a much higher altitude than current commercial flights? (15/20/30/50 km up?)

Comment: @FlorentHenry Greater height requires lower wing loading and bigger fan diameter. This will need more structure and cut into the payload fraction and should make electric propulsion look even worse. Granted, upwards of 20 km electric is becoming the only viable option since combustion engines will cease to work due to lack of sufficient partial pressure of oxygen.

Comment: @PeterKämpf different airplane shape (flying wing?), more fans, different materials could help get around the constraints of going higher up (which could require the air to be recycled and the plane to be sealed; a whole lot of different constraints for a different environment).

Comment: @FlorentHenry Believe me, a flying wing is not ideal for going high. If you want to know why, post a new question. Comments are poor for explaining controversial topics.

Answer (score 13):

Engines are great as they are. Electric engines can be fast, powerful and effective. I see two problems:

First - the sheer amount of energy consumed by the commercial airplane. With a single engine giving out 200kN you need a small power-plant attached to the aircraft. Even batteries would be 100% effective and could store enough energy, you need to burn higher amount of fuel to charge them up (you would need a A LOT of alternative energy sources to match the energy given out).

Second - it is all about the energy density. Jet fuel having 34 MJ/l , batteries having up to 120 Wh/kg = 0.36MJ/kg (according to [this site](http://www.epectec.com/batteries/cell-comparison.html) ). So you need more than 100x more space to store the same amount of energy.

Just search for the 'electric airplane' and you will get a list of mainly small, ultralight or self-propeled gliders where they don't need to carry a LOT of energy with it.

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head @GabrielVince, it's all about energy density. the best battery technology in current development has about 5-7 times a lithium ion battery, but that's still puny in comparison to hydrocarbon fuels. Even explosives don't match them for density - C4 only has 6.3 MJ/kg!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As mentioned in my question I am aware of the battery technology issues. I was wondering if there are any inherent characteristics that make electric motors unsuited for use as aircraft engines. The first paragraph of your answer indicates that this is not the case and we could build electric motors with the same capabilities as turbofans - the only (admittedly huge) problem is supplying those electric motors with enough energy.

Comment: Electric motors do not have to get all their energy from batteries. One could put a small nuclear power plant on board (perhaps not a great idea if it's fission, but if one assumes at some point small scale fusion plants are a possibility ...). Before you deride this too much, remember people said the same about nuclear powered ships / submarines.

Comment: @abligh Current nuclear-powered ships are owned and operated by militaries. They have the knowledge to handle fissile material appropriately and, perhaps more importantly, the weapons to defend it. As far as fusion is concerned, there are no current fusion reactors that produce net energy output, small-scale or otherwise. Fusion power has been "a decade or two away" since at least the 1940s.

Comment: @reirab I agree. But OP does not limit his question to civilian jets. Also OP is assuming battery technology advances hugely, so it is not unreasonable to assume fusion technology advances hugely in the same time. I think the arguments re engine weight are more pertinent than those about power sources. Arguably a nuclear powered plane would be more efficient with a turbine based system than going to electricity and back.

Comment: "One could put a small nuclear power plant on board" -- if you've got a nuclear power plant, you can use the heat from that directly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear-powered_aircraft

Comment: @GdD actually, as a general rule, explosives are not very good stores of energy at all.  They make their name not by storing a lot of energy, but by their ability to let all of that energy lose in a remarkably short period of time.

Comment: @abligh Are you saying your engineering chops are better than both of the two most advanced militaries in the world? Because neither managed to make it work.

Comment: @Aron no, I did not say *I* could get it to work. But the suggestion scientists could do something in the next 20 years they failed to do 60 years ago seems reasonable.

Comment: @abligh No. It really isn't. The problem space is simple. Nuclear reactors are radioactive. Humans and radioactivity do not mix. Shielding is heavy (scientific fact, they need to be to have a large cross-section). Heavy planes don't fly [citation needed]. Don't get me started with neutron radiation and fusion.

Comment: And - do not forget the planes crash - a few every year :) You don't want to have a crashed and malfunctioning nuclear powerplant in your garden

Comment: @abligh also people tend to get nervous when you build nuclear reactors where a massive fireball could appear (see Chernobyl, Fukushima and Windscale).

Answer (score 12):

There is one important disadvantage that batteries will always have compared with fuel combustion for aviation propulsion: the weight remains constant. Airliners (especially those used for long-haul flights) burn off a large percentage of their take-off mass over the course of the flight. Batteries, however, retain their initial mass constantly. This is a problem for a number of reasons:

1. The most obvious reason this is a problem is that more energy is required for the flight. Even if you get a battery that has equal energy density to jet fuel and is also stable (which we are currently quite far from,) the airplane will need to carry the entire mass of the batteries for the entire duration of the flight. Thus, as the flight goes on, far more energy will be used per mile on a battery-powered flight than on a fuel-powered one, even if the batteries have the same energy density as the fuel. This also means that even more battery mass will be needed for the same range, since that extra energy requirement has to come from the batteries.
2. The other big problem is maximum landing weight. Many airliners are not designed to be able to land at their maximum takeoff weight simply because it isn't needed. This is one of the reasons why fuel sometimes needs to be dumped or burnt off before an aircraft that encounters a problem after takeoff can land again. However, with batteries, you'll still be at take-off weight when you're landing, which means you'll need stronger landing gear and tires, which means yet more weight and design/manufacturing cost. It also means you'll be landing faster (because of the extra weight,) so you'll need more runway length to land as well as needing brakes that can absorb more energy. The kinetic energy of the airplane is equal to half its mass times its speed squared, so the energy that must be absorbed by the brakes during landing increases dramatically as landing weight and speed increases.
3. A somewhat less important, but still significant problem is more punishment to runway surfaces. With planes now landing near their MTOW, runways surfaces will be damaged more quickly and will need to be resurfaced more often and/or designed for larger loads than they are now. This would also probably mean that the aircraft wouldn't be able to access as many runways as an otherwise-equivalent fuel-powered aircraft would be able to use until those runways were strengthened.

Of course, you could start jettisoning battery cells as they're depleted, but this also (obviously) has a lot of problems:

1. In order to deplete some batter cells sooner than others, you won't be able to draw on all cells in parallel, which will mean higher power draw levels per cell (and, thus, more heat produced per unit time per active cell, etc.)
2. You'll need to design the airplane to be able to jettison the cells safely. This is doable, but will require lots of extra cost in design effort and extra weight.
3. Environmentalists won't be too happy when you start dropping huge batteries all over the place. Neither will property owners. Existing battery chemistries are already quite corrosive and a battery chemistry with the energy density of Jet-A is probably going to be even more corrosive, unstable, and otherwise bad for whatever it's dropped on.

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of 1 and 2 but not 3. Adds an interesting perspective; I have no idea what the costs for a resurfacing or strengthened runway design could be. However, I think if our civilization started using electric passenger jets the incentive to develop stronger runways would be big enough so that someone would come up with a solution for that particular problem (e.g., cheap new super-strong asphalt formula).

Comment: @lexeter We can build stronger runways now, it's just more expensive and doesn't happen overnight. Airports would have to have significant demand for it before they'd make the investment, especially in the case of airports where shutting a runway down to resurface causes major traffic headaches during the construction.

Comment: What about fuel cells? :)

Comment: @sanchises The question was asking specifically about batteries. Also, why would you use an electric fan with fuel cells instead of just burning the fuel directly in the engine to start with? The latter is almost certainly more efficient, not to mention less complex to design and maintain.

Comment: @reirab, a fuel cell approaches 100% efficiency at turning chemical energy into electricity.  Combustion is at best around 40% efficient.

Comment: @Mark Hmm... While Wiki is always to be taken with a grain of salt, [it claims 40-60% is typical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_cell) before considering losses in converting the electricity into propulsion. Also, like I mentioned earlier, this isn't really relevant, since the question is about batteries, not fuel cells.

Answer (score 6):

The biggest advantage of 'going' electric is that electric fans are way more efficient than a jet turbofan. A jet turbofan creates 75-85% of its thrust from the fan and 25-15% from the 'core' exhaust stream. The principle is that slower the accelerated air is, the more efficiently you generate thrust, as moving a small volume of air very fast means you lose energy in the kinetic energy of the accelerated air mass. So, bigger (or more) fans, accelerating a larger volume of air at a slower speed is much more efficient. Jet engines already do this by connecting a large fan at the front to the compressor shaft behind it, and this is a high bypass jet engine.

Even so, modern turbofans achieve under 2 Newtons of thrust per kW of energy. This is because the engine itself has low thermodynamic efficiency coupled with the fan being sub-optimised by various constraints that do not apply to an electric fan design. For example, the fans diameter is limited by ground clearance and by the RPM of the compressor drive shaft. It still rotates much too quickly and the tip velocity is capable of going supersonic. This makes for drastic drag loses and noise issues. Consequently the bypass ratio is far too low for really high efficiency, which can only really be resolved by having multiple fans. having additional contra-rotating open blades electric fans for example around the rear of the fusilage can ingest slow air from the body of the aircraft which is more efficient, and they can be placed at multiple points along the wing and tail sections.

Electric fans can, due to the approx 4 times less thermodynamic energy loses and slower tip speed, optimal RPM and slower air exit velocity potentially exceed 20N per kW, and probably get to 35N per kW.At high speeds though I don't know what performance they would achieve but it is safe to say it is going to be a LOT better than a turbofan. Consequently a battery can potentially be competitive at around 500Wh/kg, including power electronics and wiring.

Motor weights depend on power required, since as pointed out its harder to cool a large core. However you wouldn't want to try to replace the fan on a current jet engine but have multiple lower power fans, which means that the power density in kW/kg is going to be higher than in the cases listed above, superconductors not withstanding. Smaller fans also can rotate faster, suiting these kind of motors.

As pointed out above, the REAL issue is not the battery energy density but the battery POWER density - to have not only sufficient power at take-off but also to recharge within a turn around of 20-50 minutes. Since electric aircraft would first be competitive only against short to medium haul flights, a lot of which are internal and have fast turn around times, a power density of around 1kW per kg is needed, and that exceeds the current capability of high energy density batteries by a large margin.

Theoretically, if we can gain greater thrust efficiency (say 60 Newtons per kW) then we could use a lot less energy, therefore we would only need to cycle a portion of the battery capacity and could get away with, say 500W per kg charge/discharge power). In practice the power density stated is a maximum value but occurs at lower energy efficiency and tends to shorten battery life, so the battery would need to probably have a stated power density 50% more to operate efficiently this way.

110 Newtons of thrust per kW of power has been demonstrated with electrostatic ion thrusters (the type used in 'lifters' which you can see on youtube) but this have low thrust density so you have to factor in weight. Increasing the voltage will help with that.

The issue of the plane not becoming lighter as you fly is to some extent important, but the cost saving in fuel and the potential to have many fans utilised for example to assist in airflow around the wing can increase lift at low speed and thereby compensate for increased mass through out the flight envelope. The likely embodiment of contra-rotating propellers each with electrically operated variable pitch blades that can optimise both tip velocity and angle to the conditions along with accelerating a much larger volume of air more slowly will greatly increase the overall efficiency. Electric propulsion in contra-rotating fans is much easier mechanically than one hooked to a diesel or jet turbine, and can suit the high velocity of commercial aircraft (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propfan) which shows that contra-rotating ductless fans can offer efficiency advantages. Noise issues are a function of having to link these propellers to individual jet engines which again means high tip velocity as a product of the limitations on diameter and high RPM of the engine. When electrically powered, more fans can be used at much slower tip velocity, this slashes the noise produced.

The weight of the extra fans is partially offset by the gains from taking away the cowling both in weight and drag.

Because of the recharge issue, the likely embodiment will be advanced, higher efficiency engines that recharge the batteries once in cruise and descent, and top-up the energy required during climb. These could use superconducting generators and with an adequate battery reserve risk of catastrophic generator failures should be mitigated.

Comment: You can reap the increased efficiency of "electric fans" primarily by flying more slowly. Then do away with the shroud and you end up with regular propellers. Then it all makes sense.

Comment: Most batteries are able to fully recharge in less than 1 hour. Many in 30 minutes. 10 minutes to 80% charged is not out of question with adequate thermal management. I don't see this changing with increased energy density, so I don't see why power density would be an issue. But yeah, as Peter said, I would be interested in your thrust per kW at mach 0.85 speeds.

Answer (score 5):

All comments very true and valid. I would only like to add that Siemens has made and flight tested a 260kW aeroplane engine with a 5kW/kg power to weight ratio specifically for the single engine ICE type of aircraft and believes the design is scalable such that 100 seater regional series hybrids could be a reality soon. Important to note here is that hybrids address battery energy density issues as well as take-off vs landing weight and the electric motors dramatically improve the safety over conventional ICE's (internal combustion engines)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Aviation.SE.  Thanks for a good first answer. Adding references to this answer would make it even better.

Comment: Here's the link to Siemens' website regarding the mentioned aeroplane engine and its use in an Extra 330LE aerobatic airplane.
http://www.siemens.com/press/en/feature/2015/corporate/2015-03-electromotor.php?content[]=Corp

Answer (score 5):

(While this question has long been answered, I feel there's a bit that can be added as it keeps getting asked and the technology is not entirely static.)

Let's first look at the power/weight ratios. The highest number for Tesla's car motors is 8.5 kW/kg. The electric-aircraft-specific Emrax 268 delivers about 11.6 kW/kg.

In comparison, the Trent XWB delivers 430 kN of thrust at 300m/s flow rate, which equates to 64.5 MW of power, in a 7,550 kg package - a power/weight ratio of 8.5 kW/kg. However this isn't apples to oranges: this ratio is for the whole package, engine and fan, and measures useful output, like wheel power for a car.

In short, turbine engines are still lighter than electric motors, but the difference is not dramatic.
Where all-electric powerplants fail to stack up is range. I've elaborated on it in response to another question - [Are there any hybrid electric planes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53677/are-there-any-hybrid-electric-planes/53680#53680). The short version is that the maximum possible range of an electric aircraft is 10 nmi for every % of its weight dedicated to the battery. This limits the range of electric aircraft to 300-450 nmi, if sticking with the fuel fractions of known airliners.

But there are aviation applications where this is enough. The most important non-renewable resource consumed by modern aviation - the supply of 1960s Cessnas and Pipers, without which no one could afford to become a pilot - will not last forever. Should authorities permit it, mass-produced Tesla powerplants could power trainers and GA planes at a fraction of the ownership cost of a certified avgas engine.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, potentially, but there are some key differences in the comparison of a jet engine and the theoretical 'electric jet engine', that are very different from the comparison of a car engine to a motor-driven EV.

Most notably, as previously mentioned, is the turbo-fan is mechanically driven by the combustion heat-driven expansion of the air compressed by it's compressor. At cruising speeds (where the jet engine is optimized), this is a much more fuel efficient arrangement than the cruising speed operation of an automobile combustion engine.

Basically, there are two places where the released heat is converted to mechanical energy-- first, much of the heat-release of combustion is captured by the turbine that drives the compressor. Second, the exhaust nozzle also converts heat not captured by the turbine into kinetic energy by accelerating the mass-flow through the engine, converting a pressure delta generated by heat expansion into a velocity delta through nozzle geometry. By comparison, the combustion engine converts the exhaust gas heat expansion into mechanical energy by driving a linear piston, and gains no mechanical energy by exhaust. Generally, turbines are more efficient than pistons at mechanical energy conversion. There's also a tertiary efficiency-- namely that combustion at high pressures more efficiently converts heat to pressure as the gaseous density is higher, so more of the chemical energy of the fuel is converted to kinetic energy in a jet engine than a combustion engine, simply by virtue of the higher pressure of the combustion reaction in the jet engine. The 'downside' for the jet engine is that to make the whole arrangement work fuel efficiently you have to be operating at a significant fraction of Mach, much faster than ground transport can manage safely. Hence, combustion engines rule the earth and jet engines rule the sky in the current paradigm.

So, even assuming unlimited power supply, you would still have to have to have a very efficient motor on an energy cost-efficiency basis. To boot, you would have to have an engine that operated at similar cruise velocities. Even leaving aside infinite power generation, we can still consider that more time in the air is a longer time-frame along which the aircraft must be energy self-sufficient, generally equating to more mass in battery and/or power generation. More mass lowers the mechanical efficiency on an aircraft operation basis, because it is more energy you have to spend to accelerate and decelerate the extra mass.

So in an electric motor driven equivalent, you probably still have something resembling a turbo-fan. Except that your motor is primarily driving your compressor fan, and the turbine is there mostly to recapture some of the energy of compression (which also generates heat) into energy to drive certain engine functions like coolant and lubrication circulation, possibly some power regeneration. So probably a smaller turbine, but this puts you up against the inconvenient fact that compressing air is not very energy efficient as a means of generating thrust. If it were, we'd be running aircraft off compressed air.

What this generically gets at is that the electrification of air travel is likely not to resemble current jet-era technology. It's within the bounds of known technology to apply efficiency of electric motors to the problem of air transport, but the resulting architecture is likely to be very different, much as the fundamental architecture of a full EV is different than a gas automobile. This will likely in addition mean some fundamentally different infrastructure.

E.g. much of the energy of a flight is taken up in the initial acceleration, so it's possible that an Aerial EV would take off from a runway that more resembles that of an aircraft carrier than a flat road, with an assisted launch. Similarly, recapturing the energy on landing could again utilize a system more similar to those seen on aircraft carriers, only dedicated to regenerative capture rather than rapid deceleration.

More directly, though, the fundamental problem is generating thrust at near-Mach speeds. The efficiency of electrical motors at turning electrical power into rotational mechanical power is somewhat mitigated by subsonic and supersonic fluid mechanics, because an aircraft has to generate thrust by accelerating an airflow, or 'pushing' against air in some way or another. At these speeds, propellers basically start to lose their efficiency, and propulsion methods above these speeds therefore rely on the expansion of gasses with the transfer of heat into the gas. So to compete in these speed areas, an energy efficient means of transferring heat to (compressed) airflow has to be devised, which is very different than simply applying known electric motor technology.

Comment: `Except that your motor is primarily driving your compressor fan` but that's already what happens, the turbine is there just to extract the energy needed for the compressor and fan.

Comment: `much of the energy of a flight is taken up in the initial acceleration`  - only for very short range, low level flights. For any realistic condition your assumption is plain wrong and belongs in a field called ballistics.

Comment: @ Fedrico What I'm getting at is that whereas a petro-fuel jet engine is driven by it's turbine, converting heat release from fuel combustion into rotational energy to drive the compressor, an electric motor driven subsonic/hypersonic 'engine' would apply the electric motor to the compressor fan, as the the compressor would be the most mechanically efficient place to apply rotational energy driven by an electric motor. In this arrangement, it still may be energy efficient to recapture some of the energy with a turbine, but the turbine is not driving the engine, the electric motor is.

Comment: @Peterkampf, the Airbus E-Fan already applies an electric motor on it's main wheel to accelerate during takeoff, getting the aircraft to around 60 KPH. 

A ground launch assist would achieve similar effect, but reduce mass on the flight vehicle-- that launch-assist motor on the E-fan is dead weight for the rest of the flight. With ground launch assist, you might save more energy, and extend range, of an aerial EV. Particularly if the assisted launch provided 100% of energy for takeoff velocity. The Navy uses assisted launch for short takeoff, no reason it can't be used for energy efficiency.

Comment: @JasonHubbard: An aircraft with 20% fuel fraction and 25% efficiency (conversion of chemical energy into work) uses 0.0346% of the energy needed for the trip to accelerate to a take-off speed of 150 kts. On a comparable electrical aircraft you will be able to save 0.0346% of the hypothetical battery capacity by using a catapult launch, or you can stretch its range by a similar fraction. You will gain far more efficiency by e.g. choosing favorable winds enroute, or spending the catapult expense on a lighter structure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  What your question boils down to is, essentially:

> Ignoring power input, can an electrical engine produce equivalent output to a jet engine within the size and weight of that jet engine?

So:

> Is the power to weight ratio of a jet engine greater than electric engines?

and

> Is the power to volume ratio of a jet engine greater than electric engines?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-to-weight_ratio#Electric_motors.2FElectromotive_generators

The GE90-115B Brayton turbofan jet engine used on the Boeing 777 has a power to weight ratio of 10.0 kW/kg.

An electric motor made for aviation, the EMRAX268, has significantly lower power, but attains 10.0 5kW/kg.

Some will be concerned about whether the motors can scale up but as can be seen in the electric vehicle industry fast electric cars are readily available, and the size and volume of of just the motor and its required components (cooling, control) is smaller and lighter than the gas engines for those vehicles that can compete in terms of acceleration and top speed.

Even more telling is that the electric motor and its components are not only lighter and smaller, but they are cheaper as well.

The only limiting factor to electric aviation is the power source, and as a step forward every major manufacturer is already designing hybrid electric planes.  As powerful as jet engines are, they are still not as fuel efficient (and thus emissions efficient) as they could be.  A jet fuel powered generators powering electric engines may be available in the market within a decade.

These hybrid planes wouldn't be possible if the electric engines couldn't hold their own in size, weight, and power relative to a jet engine.

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing we need to start consideration is that jet engines are capable of providing a very high amount of thrust, yet they function on a simple principle of a gas turbine. Somehow it is possible to make an electric engine for propulsion but it will be complex and very heavy and lower powered. The only way an electric engine would work is to replace the jet engine core with some electric motor sort of, that can rotate the fan disk, creating thrust; however, considering how much torque is required to spin it in order to generate reasonable thrust is a nightmare, also the motor needs heavy batteries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they could.  As you said, assuming the power SUPPLY issue has been solved.  At it's heart, a jet engine heats air, harnesses the expansion to drive a compressor and in most turbofans drive the "propeller".  While presently all jet engines use burning fuel to produce that heat, the underlying principle of the system shouldn't care where the heat comes from.  If you could dump enough energy through electric heaters in the combustion section of an otherwise standard engine, I think you could in theory operate the exact same engine off of electricity.

For a modern turbofan, that'd be about 35MW of power you'd have to dump into air heaters in the "combustion" section.  This would be a pretty big engineering challenge, but I don't think it's out of the realm of possibility in theory.  One option might be using plasma sparks, like an arc welder.  Again, electrode lifespan would be an issue, but not necessarily impossible.  Credit for this idea comes from this page:
http://contest.techbriefs.com/2013/entries/aerospace-and-defense/3129

Answer (score -1):

Battery and motor technologies aside, there is one major problem with the application of electric engines on commercial aircraft and that is recharge time. Commercial aircraft only make money when they're loaded with revenue paying passengers and in the air; when they're on the ground, it's extremely costly.   Conventional chemical fuels not only pack a great deal of energy density but are also extremely easy  to replenish the supply of. Refueling a passenger plane takes a matter of minutes - in some cases as long as a half hour for say an A-380 or a 747.   Batteries currently takes hours to recharge so this would have a huge implication on the delay a passenger or cargo flights.

Personally, I  don't see an electric powered commercial aircraft as a viable alternative to current jet engines. Probably the cleanest form of air travel would be current high-efficiency jet engines powered by a carbon neutral bio diesel fuel.

Comment: The question is about engines, not batteries or fuel. Anyway, most lithium batteries accept over 1C charging current w/o significative damage, given good thermal management. That translates in 80% charge in about 30 minutes. Just look at electric cars (tesla, leaf, etc) or smartphones with quick charging.

Comment: Another solution would also be to replace (part of) the battery back, which could be easily done within minutes. However, as pointed out, the question was about engines assuming power supply is not a problem.

Comment: Then you have to figure out where to fit said battery packs in the aircraft.  It would be difficult it they were part of the wing structure.  And fuselage space is already consumed by passengers and cargo.