# Is An Electric Plane Possible?

Tags: engine

I know we have electric cars already. But in the future we’ll eventually have to use something cleaner than gasoline and gasoline is running out! So is it possible to have a battery powered turbofan plane?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! We have [many questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-engine?sort=newest&pageSize=30) about this subject already; [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26910/62) in particular might be useful for you. It's a very broad topic, so I suggest you look over the questions we already have and see if you can make your question more specific. If you aren't familiar with how the site works, you might also like to take the [tour].

Comment: Strictly no, because a battery-powered turbofan is a contradiction in terms (like an electric-powered internal combustion engine).  But yes, there are flyable electric planes that exist today.  Google will return ~5 million hits.