# Why can’t electric motors be used in aviation

Tags: engine, turbofan, propulsion, airplane, electric-engine

Why can’t electric motors be used in aviation? Is it a problem with batteries, torque, or what? From what I’m aware motors at high torque are expensive and need a massive footprint, than a high rpm low torque motor. Is the issue the weight and size of a motor to lift 500,000 pounds off the ground? We have motors right now that can spin a turbo fan at a high speed and compute a comparable thrust, but is that thrust under load a different story? Is the energy required way too much for a realistic battery size?

Comment: It's not the motor, it's the weight of the batteries.  There are some electric aircraft, but their endurance is quite limited, or they have impractical for general use wingspans &c: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_aircraft

Comment: @jamesqf that's good enough to be an answer.  You should maybe expand it a bit and post it.

Comment: Electric power does not need to be delivered by batteries, fuel cells or a generator work as well.

Comment: @John K: There are already several questions with answers saying essentially the same thing.

Comment: @Koyovis: Fuel cells need to carry fuel, and AFAIK are fairly rate-limited.  Using a generator to produce electricity to run an electric motor that drives your propellor would be stupidly inefficient.  Though one might consider solar power, as with the Solar Impulse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Impulse to be a sort of generator.  But again, it's hardly suited to practical uses.

Comment: @jamesqf Hydrogen in fuel cells does not weigh very much. Hybrid cars are stupidly inefficient?

Comment: Electric motors most certainly are used for propulsion in aviation in the present day.  An ideal application is a self-launching sailplane with some amount of long-duration sustainer/ cruise capability.  Examples-- https://www.icaro2000.com/Products/Swift/Swift.htm and http://www.alisport.com/?product=silent-2-electro-2 .  I would like to be able to add this comment as an actual answer but apparently I cannot since the question has been ruled to be a duplicate that has already been answered.

Comment: Moderators, the question is not a duplicate, see my comment/ answer above, it does not appear to be an applicable answer to the other questions to which this question is supposedly a duplicate of.

Comment: Added to second comment above this one-- obviously, the reliability of starting/ ease of starting an electric motor is a huge asset in this application as it is expected to be started in flight if soaring conditions deteriorate.

Comment: @Koyovis: 1) Enough hydrogen to propel a plane does weigh quite a bit, but the real problem is the containers.  You either need high-strength tanks for gas (ever hauled around scuba tanks?), or you need insulation and/or refrigeration equipment to keep it liquid.  2) Hybrid cars do not use generators, they use regenerative braking.  Their efficiency is principally a reflection that it takes a lot more power to accelerate than to maintain steady speed, so the electric assist allows a smaller, more efficient engine.  Airplanes fly at close to full power, and seldom brake :-)

Comment: They can, but it's a nascent field. [Harbour Air and magniX Announce Successful Flight of World’s First Commercial Electric Airplane](https://www.harbourair.com/harbour-air-and-magnix-announce-successful-flight-of-worlds-first-commercial-electric-airplane/)

Answer (score 2):

Electric motors can be and are used in aviation - there's hundreds of them on any airliner you fly on.

As for using them for main propulsion, let's first look at the power/weight ratios. The highest number for Tesla's car motors is 8.5 kW/kg. The electric-aircraft-specific Emrax 268 delivers about 12 kW/kg.

In comparison, the Trent XWB delivers 430 kN of thrust at 300m/s flow rate, which equates to 64.5 MW of power, in a 7,550 kg package - a power/weight ratio of 8.5 kW/kg. However this isn't apples to oranges: this ratio is for the whole package, engine and fan, and measures useful output, like wheel power for a car.

In short, turbine engines are still lighter than electric motors, but the difference is not dramatic.
Where all-electric powerplants fail to stack up is range. I've elaborated on it in response to another question - [Are there any hybrid electric planes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53677/are-there-any-hybrid-electric-planes/53680#53680). The short version is that the maximum possible range of an electric aircraft is 10 nmi for every % of its weight dedicated to the battery. This limits the range of electric aircraft to 300-450 nmi, if sticking with the fuel fractions of known airliners.

But there are aviation applications where this is enough. The most important non-renewable resource consumed by modern aviation - the supply of 1960s Cessnas and Pipers, without which no one could afford to become a pilot - will not last forever. Should authorities permit it, mass-produced Tesla powerplants could power trainers and GA planes at a fraction of the ownership cost of a certified avgas engine.

Comment: Cessnas AND Pipers!

Comment: Emrax 268 delivers up to 10kW/kg https://emrax.com/products/emrax-268/

Comment: @jamesqf, [magnix](https://www.magnix.aero/news/) just powered the first commercial plane w/electric, a little bigger motor, [magni500 560kW](https://www.magnix.aero/products/) on a DHC-2Beaver